# PHP: What is wrong with this preg_match that is converted from ereg

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, ereg

I've seen similar questions on here, but I don't think any of them helped with this.

I've inherited a site from someone who used an older version of PHP and specifically the ereg function.  Their original reg ex was:

```
$regex = "[ ]+[0-9]+) ( [a-zA-Z]+)[ ]+Crimson[ ]+([0-9]+)[ ]+[0-9]+[ ]+[0-9]+[ ]+[0-9]+[ ]+([0-9]+)[ ]+[0-9]+";
```

I've read that you need to start and end with a delimiter, so i've updated it to:

```
$regex = "/[ ]+[0-9]+) (    [a-zA-Z]+)[ ]+Crimson[ ]+([0-9]+)[ ]+[0-9]+[ ]+[0-9]+[ ]+[0-9]+[ ]+([0-9]+)[ ]+[0-9]+/";
```

But I am still getting this error:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at
>   offset 10

I don't see any special characters in the expression, so I am unsure as to what else I need to escape.  Any ideas?

Comment: There's a closing bracket after the first `[0-9+)` - there's no matching opening one.

Comment: Let's see... **unmatched parentheses**... the first paren in the expression (the one at offset 10) is *closing* instead of opening... hmmm....

Comment: You should use a repetition operator instead of copy&pasting `[0-9]` in sequence.

Comment: and also why there is more spaces at your second regex?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `)` near the beginning of your regexp, but you didn't open that. If it's literal, add backslash before it.

```
/[ ]+[0-9]+)
```

to

```
/[ ]+[0-9]+\)
```

If not, open it first.

Comment: Ahh that was it.  The ) was actually suppose to be literal so I escaped it.  Thank you very much for pointing this out. That was definitely going to be one of those that I spend 4 hours looking for and only find at the very last moment!

Answer (score 1):

At position 10 you have an closing ) , without an opening (